# Как сделать замену по регулярному выражению?

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь сделать на php свой шаблонизатор, сейчас я делаю цыклы. Вот пример цикла:

```
[[ @times(5) ]]
  <p>{{ $message }}</p>
[[ @times(#end) ]]
```

Код выше просто выводит {{ $message }} пять раз. И все хорошо, но если использовать вложенные циклы, например:

```
[[ @times(5) ]]
  [[ @times(2) ]]
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
  [[ @times(#end) ]]
[[ @times(#end) ]]
```

то результат будет таким:

```
[[ @times(5) ]]
    Hello world!
    Hello world!
[[ @times(#end) ]]
```

Как сделать чтобы внутренний цикл срабатывал нормально?

Я использую следующий код обработки таких конструкций:

```
public static function dirs($code, $data) {
    $pattern = '/\[\[\s*@([^\(]+)\(([^\)]+)\)\s*\]\]([^\[]+)\[\[\s*@([^\(]+)\(#end\)\s*\]\]/i';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($value) use($data) {
      if($value[1] == 'times') return str_repeat($value[3], $value[2]); // $value[3] - строка <p>{{ $message }}</p>, $value[2] = 5;
    }, $expression);
  }
```

Тут я просто ищу все конструкии такого вида [[ @times(n) ]] Some text... [[ @times(#end) ]], и вывожу их n раз
Как сделать чтобы внутренний цикл срабатывал нормально?

UPD: Переменная $message равна "Hello world!"

Comment: вы думаете сделаете удобнее и эффективней чем twig/smarty ? или каков смысл?

Comment: Я хочу понять как работают шаблонизаторы, использовать их в реал проектах не собираюсь)

Comment: дак вот и изучите, как работают упомянутые выше (:

Comment: я хочу свой создать)